# Trying to find a method to refactor my function to make it more efficient

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, callback, refactoring

I have this function as seen below that groups an array of numbers based on a length parameter. The length represents the max length of each sub-array. What I am trying to figure out, is a method I can take to shift `x => x % 2` out of the declaration of the result variables and into the function. The only thing I could think of would be a callback, but I am not sure how I could do this. Any help with this is appreciated and if you notice any other redundant code please let me know.

```
function myFunc(arr, length, fnc) {
  groups = []; 
  result  = [];
  for (let val of arr) {
    x = fnc(val);
    if (!groups[x]) {
      groups[x] = [];
    }
    if (!groups[x].length) {
      result .push(groups[x]);
    }
    groups[x].push(val);
    if (groups[x].length === length) {
      groups[x] = [];
    }
  }
  return result ;
}
//examples
const result1 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 2, x => x % 2)
console.log(result1) //[[1, 3], [2, 4]]

const result2 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4, x => x % 2)
console.log(result2) //[[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6]]

const result3 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1, x => x % 2)
console.log(result3) //[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

const result4 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4, x => x % 2)
console.log(result4) //[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

What Id like to achieve is only needing to call the array and the size of the sub-arrays that Id like to create. Just a brief understanding of what is happening, the arrays are based off seeing whether they can make a full array to the size of "length," and any overflow is pushed to another sub-array. An example of this looks like this:

```
console.log(myfunc([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],3))
```

This would return `[[1,3,5][2,4,6][7,9][8,10]]`

So if someone could assist me in removing the fnc parameter from the console.log statements and placing it into the function, it would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you know this parameter will always be the same, so there's 
no need to write it every time; it can just be baked into the function.

At its most simplest, you can literally just take `fnc` out of the parameter list and declare it manually as a variable, always setting it to the same value:

```js
function myFunc(arr, length) {
  let fnc = x => x % 2;
  groups = []; 
  result  = [];
  for (let val of arr) {
    x = fnc(val);
    if (!groups[x]) {
      groups[x] = [];
    }
    if (!groups[x].length) {
      result .push(groups[x]);
    }
    groups[x].push(val);
    if (groups[x].length === length) {
      groups[x] = [];
    }
  }
  return result ;
}

//examples
const result1 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
console.log(result1) //[[1, 3], [2, 4]]

const result2 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4)
console.log(result2) //[[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6]]

const result3 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)
console.log(result3) //[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

const result4 = myFunc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4)
console.log(result4) //[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

At this point there really isn't almost any point to `fnc` being a function though. It's the same operation every time. Just take that operation and paste it in place of the function call. Also, you should always use `let` or `const` to declare things, don't just assign them with no declaration keyword - that makes them globals and they might interact with your global namespace in an unexpected way. Finally, I urge you to rename your function to something that describes what it does. This helps everyone reading your code understand it more intuitively, including your future self.

This is what that all would look like:

```js
function splitArray(arr, length) {
  let groups = []; 
  let result = [];
  for (let val of arr) {
    let x = val % 2; //this does the same thing
    if (!groups[x]) {
      groups[x] = [];
    }
    if (!groups[x].length) {
      result.push(groups[x]);
    }
    groups[x].push(val);
    if (groups[x].length === length) {
      groups[x] = [];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//examples
const result1 = splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
console.log(result1) //[[1, 3], [2, 4]]

const result2 = splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 4)
console.log(result2) //[[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6]]

const result3 = splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)
console.log(result3) //[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]

const result4 = splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4)
console.log(result4) //[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I totally agree with what you've said.